# Host and device protection needed for designing for USB type 3.0 powered electronics?

Tags: power-supply, usb, usb-device, circuit-protection, peripheral

I am designing a switch-mode variable power supply (that can boost) intended to run on USB type 3.0 (be powered by a PC/laptop USB port say). Being that I am quite naive to computer electronics I am instinctively unsure what happens if I short my power supply accidentally, although I assume it varies between machine.

My question is then what protections should I implement on my end to reasonably expect it to work on most machines without breaking something (i.e. strict current limiting and whatnot). Thanks

Comment: try adding a fuse to the circuit

Comment: furthemore, windows pop up warnings when an external machine needs high current, and limits the current passing through the usb port.